# How can I use sed to replace ':' (a colon) with ' - ' (a hyphen with white space on either side) inside of an environment variable?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following inside of an environment variable (using Ubuntu):

```
variable="Hello: User"
```

If I do:

```
echo $variable
Hello: User
```

What I need to do is replace the `:` with `-` inside `$variable`.

```
echo $(echo $variable | sed '')
```

But I don't know how to use sed with a variable like this one.

My expected output from this command would be:

```
"Hello - User"
```

Comment: `echo "${variable//:/ -}"`

Comment: Also, you should (almost) always double-quote variable references. That is, use `echo "$variable"` instead of just `echo $variable`

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Notice that if you actually replaced "a colon with a hyphen with white space on either side", you'd get `Hello -  User`, i.e., two blanks after the hyphen. Also, when you show your expected output, the double quotes aren't really expected, are they?

Comment: read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes before writing any other commands and run all your scripts through http://shellcheck.net until you get some familiarity with shell programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Bash string manipulation:

```
echo "${variable/:/ -}"
```

It will replace the first `:` with `space` + `-`.

Comment: to replace all colons it would be: `echo "${variable//:/ -}"`